# Dojo FilteringSelect autocomplete search through http query

Tags: javascript, dojo

Can dijit.form.FilteringSelect generate a seperate autocompletion http query each time user enters different value into textbox ?

AFAIK currently filtering based on this string is done at client side. I'd like to perform this filtering at server side.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you can use a [dojox.data.QueryReadStore](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/dojox/data/QueryReadStore) as the specified `store` when you create the filtering select and it will use the server for filtering.  Your server endpoints will have to implement the proper contract though, as detailed in `Server Side Implementation` [here](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojox/data/QueryReadStore.html)

```
var dataStore = new dojox.data.QueryReadStore({
  url: '/some/filtering/endpoint'
});

var filteringSelect = new dijit.form.FilteringSelect({
 store: dataStore
});
```

Comment: Thank You. I found this usefull http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojox/data/QueryReadStore

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/) says : "If you type in some text then it will filter down the list of possible values in the drop down list. - List can be specified **either as a static list or via a javascript function** (that can get the list from a server)"

So... try the javascript function method ;-)